# Homotopy extension property of subcategory

Tags: ct.category-theory

I am wondering about an analog of the homotopy extension property in the setting of a pair $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{S})$ where $\iota : \mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{C}$ is a subcategory.

Explicitly, I say the pair $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{S})$ has the homotopy extension property if for any functors $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ and $G : \mathcal{S} \to \mathcal{D}$ along with a natural transformation $\eta : F \circ \iota \to G$ there exits a functor $G' : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ such that $G = G' \circ \iota$ and a natural transformation $\eta' : F \to G'$ restricting to $\eta$.

I am wondering if this notion has been studied and if there are any nice results on when such a pair has this homotopy extension property (HEP).

What happens if we replace "natural transformation" with "natural isomorphism"? I am actually interested in the version where $F, G : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ are specified along with a natural isomorphism over $\mathcal{S}$ which I want to extend to $\mathcal{C}$.

Some remarks:

(1) if $\iota$ is an equivalence then $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{S})$ has HEP

(2) let $I = \{ a \to b \}$ be the interval category. If $(\mathcal{S} \times I) \cup (\mathcal{C} \times \{ a \}) \to \mathcal{C} \times I$ has a left inverse then $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{S})$ has HEP where $\cup$ denotes the smallest subcategory containing both.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the natural isomorphism case, such an inclusion functor is also called a cofibration of categories.  In fact they are the cofibrations in the [canonical model structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/canonical+model+structure+on+Cat) on $Cat$, and they are characterized as the functors that are injective on objects (hence, in particular, include *all* actual subcategory inclusions).

I don't know what happens if you consider extending noninvertible transformations.  In that case you would have two different notions of, say, "lax cofibration" and "colax cofibration".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a little confused because I think the map from a category to its skeleton should be a cofibration but obviously is not injective on objects. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @BenC In the canonical model structure every category is fibrant, so any trivial cofibration is a split monomorphism. Concretely, consider the map from a two-object simply connected groupoid $G$ to the terminal category, it doesn’t have the natural isomorphism extension property with respect to the identity of $G$.